# Importing previously exported models

Tags: origen-sdk

I'm trying to track down an issue where the Origen import command isn't loading a previously exported model.  I see in the exported rb file there's a module and a method called self.extended.  The import command is loading the module, so that I can manually do .extended(dut), but I shouldn't have to run it explicitly.  Tracing through the import code I don't see where the extended method is called.  My question is: by design. how is module import supposed to work?  Where should that extended method be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, application code should not have to call the extended method directly.

Perhaps the issue has been introduced by the changes in this PR? - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/pull/221

To your question, this is where extended gets called - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/blob/master/lib/origen/model/exporter.rb#L80

However, it is not called directly, extended is a hook provided by Ruby which will be automatically called whenever an object extends a module - https://www.sitepoint.com/rubys-important-hook-methods/

Comment: Thanks @Ginty.  This makes sense.  I'll have to dig more into it to figure out why the built-in Ruby hook isn't being called on extend.